# Fantasy novel that starts with a woman on a horse being attacked by scorpions and has a thief with a death wish named Fly

Tags: story-identification

This is another vaguely remembered fantasy novel that I read around high school (somewhere in the 90s). It was in English, read in the United States, and I think it was a hardback. The two things that stuck with me:

- The book opened with a scene with a man and a woman on a horse and they're being attacked by hordes of scorpions (probably magically summoned ones). The man has summoned a ring of fire around them, but the scorpions eventually make their way through on the bodies of their dead and get the man and woman. For some reason, I'm convinced that this was a vision, possibly being experienced from the main character.
- Shortly into the story, the main character encounters a hapless thief named Fly, or maybe The Fly. Said thief, for some reason, had a death wish and tried to attack the protagonist so that he could be killed. I want to say that he, on foot, charged the protagonist, who was on horsebook, sword held high. The protagonist disarms him at least twice before they stop and talk.

Unfortunately, that's all that I can remember, but the images are currently stuck in my head, so I'm trying to find the book so I can put it out of mind once more.

Comment: In The Changing Land by Zelazny there is a scene where two men (on foot) and a pack horse are attacked by scorpions and use circles of flame to attempt to hold them off. I don't think there is any character called Fly though.

Comment: My library doesn't carry that one. I'll see if I can get it via ILL, but the description on Goodreads doesn't sound at all familiar.

Comment: @JohnRennie: ILL delivered a copy, and the scene with the horses and scorpions and circles rings true, but nothing about Fly yet.